# How do you enable excel add-ins for all users using registry (HKLM)?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, windows-scripting, registrykey

I'm trying to enable an excel add-in for all users in a given lab (Office 2019 is installed). The path to the add-in's "OPEN" string in the registry is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\options. Before scripting anything for deployment, I'm just trying to manually test where I can enable that same add-in for HKLM and have it work for another test user.

I've tried creating my own key for the add-in under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Addins (Addins is a key I added manually), however so far I haven't had any luck.

I've seen other people mention this issue in other posts, but the answers weren't very clear to me and many of these posts were from 5+ years ago, so I'm hoping there's a more up-to-date solution I can utilize. Please let me know if you have any knowledge on this particular problem. Thank you!

I'm a bit of a noob with this sort of thing still, so thorough (even verbose) answers are extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a per user delegation.  You need to use a GPO to set the reg key for the users as they login.